# Rails newbie : How to add cover image to a model belonging to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, model

I'm new to rails and probably miss-understanding, missing something may be idiot.

I have a `progress_board` model, controller and view. Each `has_many :progress_board_metrics` which belongs_to it.

This `progress_board` model has a **cover_image** param as follow :

```
lass ProgressBoard < ApplicationRecord
    validates :name, presence: true
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :progress_board_metrics, dependent: :destroy
    has_attached_file :cover_image

    def assign_cover_image
        if ci = params[:progress_board][:cover_image]
         cover_image = ci
      end
        cover_image = File.open(cover_image_path)
        self.cover_image = cover_image
        self.save
    end
end
```

This one is working fine

By side, I want to add a **cover_image** to my `progress_board_metrics` model which has no controller or view (again, it belongs to `progress_board`)

I'm trying like this :

```
class ProgressBoardMetric < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :progress_board

  has_attached_file :cover_image

    def assign_cover_image
        if ci = params[:X][:cover_image]
         cover_image = ci
      end
        cover_image = File.open(cover_image_path)
        self.cover_image = cover_image
        self.save
    end
```

**Problem is** : I don't know what to put inside the **[:X]**. I tried with "progress_board_metric**s**", "progress_board_metric", "metric"

I'm lost at this point

Comment: Are you even sure the first example is working? `params` should not be accessible inside the model in the first place.
And if you want to do changes to the progress_board_metric you should still at least have a controller for it

Comment: Paperclip is deprecated. If you are new to rails, I suggest you switch to use Active Storage. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html